# I would to extract records which has a certain period in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I everyone, I would to extract all the records from my table which are > from a certain period.
For example,I have my column END_STATE that is Timestamp and has values for example like `04-NOV-21 08:35:24,000000000`. I would to extract all the records which have END_STATE > '09:00'. How can I do?

Comment: Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include what you tried ....  Reading this will help too: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `extract`.

Sample data; only ID = 2 has end date which is after 09:00:

```
with test (id, end_date) as
   (select 1, to_timestamp('04.11.2021 08:35:24,000000000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss,ff9') from dual
     union all
     select 2, to_timestamp('06.03.2022 15:25:43,000000000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss,ff9') from dual
     union all
     select 3, to_timestamp('15.06.2023 00:00:15,000000000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss,ff9') from dual
    )
  select * From test
  where extract(hour from end_date) > 9;
```

| ID | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 06.03.22 15:25:43,000000000 |

Comment: okok, thank you but, if for example I have two different timestamp from two different table. For example in table1 I have END_DATE like 04-NOV-21 08:35:24,000000000, and in table2 I have END_DATE like  04-NOV-22 08:35:24,000000000. How can I do to compare this two timestamps? In this case i would to extract ONLY 04-NOV-21 = 04-NOV-22. How can I do?

Comment: Hi , you want to use to_char and get the month & day from the timestamp and compare the values , select systimestamp, trunc(systimestamp), to_char(systimestamp, 'mm-dd') from dual

Comment: @MarioS: The question you are asking in the comments is **very** different form the question in the question....  Please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77703415/edit) to improve the question!